# Having trouble running my program via the getRuntime() in Java

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have the following class :

After compiling my CreateTexts.java class, I want to run it via getRuntime (calling it through Eclipse ). So I run this class

```
public class RuntimeDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {

   // create a new array of 2 strings
   String[] cmdArray = new String[2];

   // first argument is the program we want to open
   //C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
   cmdArray[0] = "C://Program Files//Java//jdk1.6.0_20//bin//java";

   // second argument is a txt file we want to open with notepad


  cmdArray[1] = "C://logback//CreateTexts";



   // create a process and execute cmdArray and currect environment
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null);


   } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   }

   }
}
```

But I'm not seeing the output file being created. Any tips appareciated thanks

Comment: i believ i need to use ProcessBuilder class , not this way

Comment: Why not simply call batch file in jthis code, let the batch file do the job of running your `CreateTexts` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are running the program is wrong.

Let's suppose you `CreateTexts` is inside the package `logback`. And the file is located in `"C://logback//CreateTexts"`, then you have to `cd` to `C:` and then execute the program as `java logback.CreateTexts`.

Just directly calling the file using absolute path from any directory wont work.

Comment: hmm, but how come I was able to compile it from Eclipse (which is in some random dir. ) ?

Comment: or i'm guessing thats a java security mechanism or smth ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415507/how-can-i-compile-and-run-a-java-class-in-a-different-directory - i think this clarifies

Comment: @Coffee, yes.. Instead of `cd`ing to the directory.. You can also add it to the classpath as mentioned in the answer in link...